# MVVMLight ViewModelLocator registering dataservice

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

This question might look naive, but I couldn't understand this code in the ViewModelLocator.cs file:

```cs
static ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
    }
    else
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();         
    }

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
}
```

I see that we use a DataService to get data (from WCF service for example) and assigning it to the MainViewModel. But what if I'm registering more than one ViewModel? like this:

```cs
static ViewModelLocator()
{
    ....
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Page2ViewModel>();
}
```

and let's say I have another DataService (DataService2 for example), but this one I'll use with the Page2ViewModel. how can I do that?

Also, if someone can help me (or even give me a link to read) about the above code. I have no clue what it means.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are not assigning any `IDataService` to the `MainViewModel` here. You are registering a type mapping, so your container will be aware that it should return a `DataService` whenever an `IDataService` required.

This is related to **dependency injection** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

The DI container **auto-wires** the dependencies, so when you need a specific type, you can call

`ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDataService>()`

or

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>()
```

etc. *If it can build it* (so you registered your types), it will resolve the full dependency graph for you.

For example, if your `MainViewModel` has a constructor dependency on `IDataService`, and you are not in design mode, a `DataService` will be injected to the `MainViewModel` constructor. Don't be afraid from the buzzword *injected*, it is just a call to the MainViewModel constructor with the appropriate parameters :).

So, `MainViewModel` will not interference with `Page2ViewModel` here.

I made a simple sample for you to demonstrate what happens (I used Unity, http://unity.codeplex.com/ , but the syntax is almost the same):

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IService, Service1>();
        container.RegisterType<IService, Service2>("MySpecificService");
        container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>();
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator(container));

        var viewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        viewModel.Foo();
    }
}

interface IService
{
}

interface IRepository
{   
}

class Service1 : IService
{
    public Service1(IRepository repository)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service1 created");
    }
}

class Service2 : IService
{
    public Service2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service2 created");
    }
}

class Repository : IRepository
{
    public Repository()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Repository created");
    }
}

class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel(IService service)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MainViewModel created");
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        var specificService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IService>("MySpecificService");
    }
}
```

the output is:

```cs
Repository created
Service1 created
MainViewModel created
Service2 created
```

Because you need a `MainViewModel` (maybe in SimpleIoC you need to register MainViewModel too, in Unity, it can resolve concrete classes without mapping), the container trying to create one, but it realizes that `MainViewModel` needs an `IService`, and it finds the default one from the mapping, which is `Service1`, but it realizes that `Service1` needs an `IRepository`, and it finds the default one, so it can pass a `Repository` to the `Service1` constructor, then the `Service1` instance to the `MainViewModel` constructor. All the dependencies resolved.

The `Foo` call is an example how you can register more than one type to the same interface. Dependency injection is a much more bigger topic, but auto-wiring is an important part of it.